# How can I implement a timeout on waiting on a semaphore or locked file in PHP?

Tags: php, timeout, semaphore

I am searching a way to put timeout on waiting for a locked file or a semaphore, so when it takes too long, the code has alternate way to handle things.

Timeout option is available for network functions, I am looking for local machine operations.

This operation should not implement looping or PHP ticks as not to load the CPU.

Comment: Locked file: using blocking I/O and/or [`flock()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.flock.php), that's what they're for. Semaphore: https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.sem.php